# I want to add a new line at a interval of every third element of a list of 9 elements. I also want only two '\n' in the list. Please help me out

Tags: python

The code is given below.

```
board = []

yes = 0

board.extend('-' * 9)

for index, i in enumerate(board):

   if index % 4 == 0 and yes < 3:
      board.insert(index-1 ,'\n')
      yes += 1

print(board)
```

This code gives a input like:
['-',  '-',  '-',  '\n',  '-',  '-',  '-',  '\n',  '-',  '-',  '\n',  '-']

I cant understand why the third '\n' is coming.

Comment: Don't change `board` while iterating it

Comment: Modifying an object while you're iterating it makes things complicated (though it can be done). For the sake of getting-things-done w/o pulling your hair out, you should consider to build a new list instead.

Comment: The simplest way will be to use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join): `board = '\n'.join(['-'*3] * 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`enumerate` has a `start` parameter which you can use

```
board = []

yes = 0

board.extend('-' * 9)

for index, i in enumerate(board,start=1):

   if index % 4 == 0:
      board.insert(index-1 ,'\n')

print(board)
```

Comment: Be careful, if `i` will ever be used in the loop then there will be a mismatch between the index and the value of `i`. Either signify it is not being used by renaming it to `_`, use `board[1:]` or just use `for index in range(1, len(board))` although the latter is considered to be less idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

It happend when you check `index % 4 == 0`, `index=0` also fits this condition.

`index % 4 == 0`

`0 % 4 == 0 - True`.

Then you use `index - 1` in `insert` and get `index = -1`. If you try to use this code that I wrote below, you get your problem

```
board = []
board.extend('-' * 9)

board.insert(-1, '\n')
print(board)


Output: ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '\n', '-']
```

Comment: The quickest fix is to just use `for index, i in enumerate(board[1:], 1):`, which eliminates dealing with `index == 0` without needing to check it in every iteration